# BehaviorSubject subscribe on another thread

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm new to RxJava and I chose to use it because I thought it would be well suited to my use case.

I have some `Integer` values I want to observe over an infinite period of time. Whenever one of these values changes (i.e. an event) I want all of its observers to be called on **another thread**.

Because of the long observation time requirement I thought I needed to use the `BehaviorSubject` class (although initially I thought `Observable` was all that I needed .. seeing as I just need to 'observe'), and I could use the `subscribeOn()` method to set a scheduler  and hence achieve calling the subscribers on a background thread:

```
private BehaviorSubject<Integer> rotationPositionSubject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(getRotorPosition());
rotationPositionSubject.subscribeOn(scheduler);
```

And I have a `rotate()` method I used to update the `rotationPositionSubject` which will be called from the main thread:

```
@Override
public synchronized int rotate()
{
    final int newRotorPosition = super.rotate();
    rotationPositionSubject.onNext(newRotorPosition);

    return newRotorPosition;
}
```

However with the above code I found that the subscribers are called on the 'main' thread. Examining the docs for [subscribeOn()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribeOn-io.reactivex.Scheduler-):

> **Returns:**
>
> the source ObservableSource modified so that its subscriptions happen on the specified Scheduler

So my above code won't work as I am not using the returned ObservableSource, but the return object is an `Observable` which is of no use for my application?

The question is then, how do I observe long-term any object and call subscribers on a background thread with RxJava, or is RxJava the wrong choice?

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]? Also there is also an `observeOn()` you can use. And you are using the `Observable` object to use its `subscribe()` method to react on new values.

Comment: @Progman I've added in the method to show how I am using the `rotationPositionSubject`. `observeOn()`  also returns and `Observable` which leaves me in the same position as I described above.

Comment: Please show the code where you are reading the values from the `Subject`. It sounds weird that you don't use the `Observable` object since you have to use it for the `subscribe()` method to get the data from the source. Anyway, the methods `observeOn()` and `subscribeOn()` should switch the thread. If they don't please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation it looks as though one needs some care when using `BehaviorSubject` objects and their use isn't quite as obvious as I inferred from the names of the various interfaces.

As a test method to demonstrate what I am currently doing:

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    System.out.println("Executing test on thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    final BehaviorSubject<Integer> rotorBehaviour = BehaviorSubject.create();
    rotorBehaviour.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single());
    rotorBehaviour.subscribe(new Observer<Integer>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(final Disposable d)
        {
            System.out.println("onSubscribe() called on thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(final Integer integer)
        {
            System.out.println("onNext() called on thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(final Throwable e)
        {
            System.out.println("onError() called on thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete()
        {
            System.out.println("onComplete() called on thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
    });


    rotorBehaviour.onNext(1);
    rotorBehaviour.onNext(2);

}
```

This results in the undesired result:

> Executing test on thread ID: 1
>   onSubscribe() called on thread ID: 1
>   onNext() called on thread ID: 1
>   onNext() called on thread ID: 1
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

(Undesired because `onNext()` is called on the main thread)

Modifying the code to use the `Observable` returned from the call to `subscribeOn` gives the same undesired result:

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    System.out.println("Executing test on thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    final BehaviorSubject<Integer> rotorBehaviour = BehaviorSubject.create();
    Observable<Integer> rotorObservable = rotorBehaviour.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single());

    rotorObservable.subscribe(new Observer<Integer>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(final Disposable d)
        {
            System.out.println("onSubscribe() called on thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(final Integer integer)
        {
            System.out.println("onNext() called on thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(final Throwable e)
        {
            System.out.println("onError() called on thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete()
        {
            System.out.println("onComplete() called on thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
    });
    rotorBehaviour.onNext(1);
    rotorBehaviour.onNext(2);
}
```

Result:

> Executing test on thread ID: 1
>   onSubscribe() called on thread ID: 1
>   onNext() called on thread ID: 1
>   onNext() called on thread ID: 1
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

However using the `observeOn()` method does give the desired result:

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    System.out.println("Executing test on thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    final BehaviorSubject<Integer> rotorBehaviour = BehaviorSubject.create();
    Observable<Integer>rotorObservable = rotorBehaviour.observeOn(Schedulers.single());

    rotorObservable.subscribe(new Observer<Integer>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(final Disposable d)
        {
            System.out.println("onSubscribe() called on thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(final Integer integer)
        {
            System.out.println("onNext() called on thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(final Throwable e)
        {
            System.out.println("onError() called on thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete()
        {
            System.out.println("onComplete() called on thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
    });
    rotorBehaviour.onNext(1);
    rotorBehaviour.onNext(2);
}
```

> Executing test on thread ID: 1
>   onSubscribe() called on thread ID: 1
>   **onNext() called on thread ID: 13**
>   **onNext() called on thread ID: 13**
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Also in all of the examples I am still using the `BehaviorSubject` object to initiate an event and I only found out by accident that this will give the desired result.

What concerns me is that I may be using `Observable` and `BehaviorSubject` in an incorrect way that just 'happens' to give me the correct result i.e. subscribers are called on the background thread. Unless I've missed it somewhere in the documentation it doesn't appear obvious how to use these objects to get the desired result.

Comment: A `BehaviorSubject` is used for a subject which always should have a value returned when you subscribe to it. You will get the "last" value which was added. An `Observable` is the default way to get the values from a source via a subscription you build with `subscribe()`. The method `observeOn()` specifies a thread(pool) where the listeners should be run, otherwise the "message" will be send/processed on the thread, which did the `onNext()` call.

Comment: I'm not really sure of the point you are making. All I wanted to achieve was to 'observe' an object, in my case an `Integer`, for an indefinite amount of time and when it changes (by being altered from the main thread)  I want all subscribers/observers (I used the terms interchangeably here because I am not clear on the difference) to be 'called' on a background thread. I thought I had used the interfaces in an intuitive way (based on their names) but it looks as though RxJava isn't as straight-forward as I hoped. If you've an example of what I want to achieve I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: The subscribers/observers register them self with the `subscribe()` method on the `Observable` object. When the original source is changed (via an onNext() call or via some complicated subscription based on other sources) all the registered subscribers/observers gets informed, their `onNext()` method gets called. Keep in mind that these happens synchronously. The original `onNext()` call on the source will reach the `onNext()` calls on the same thread. If you don't want that (because it's time consuming), you use `observeOn()`to make the jump to a different thread(pool).